# Limit the number Of Decimal Points Returned on Longitude and Latitude in Google API Map

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in my script. I would like to limit the number to about 6 digits past the decimal returned on the pin marker. Currently I get about 15 digits past the decimal.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: + location.lat() + ',' + location.lng()
   // ...
});
```

Comment: "About"? Why so vague?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to *always* have six digits after the decimal, even if they are zeroes, you could do:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:
        location.lat().toFixed(6) +
        ',' +
        location.lng().toFixed(6)
});
```

Or if you want to remove trailing zeros and also remove the decimal point if the value is a whole number, you could do this:

```
function formatDecimal( number, precision ) {
    return number.toFixed( precision ).replace( /[\.]?0+$/, '' );
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:
        formatDecimal( location.lat(), 6 ) +
        ',' +
        formatDecimal( location.lng(), 6 )
});
```

BTW, this is a JavaScript question, not a Google Maps API question.  `location.lat()` and `location.lng()` are JavaScript numbers, so you use JavaScript code to format them as you like. (I'm mentioning this only because it will help you find answers to your coding questions faster.)